# Get value from Array inside of an Array

Tags: php, arraylist

I have the following string output if I run `print_r($val)`:

`{"next_offset":-1,"records":[{"id":"e3266222-5389-11ed-ab30-0210c01ad3d2","name":"That is a nice name"}]}`

Now, I need the value of attribute "id". Sounds simple but I'm not able getting there.

Answer (score -1):

Does something like this work?

I'm assuming `$val` is a json string.

```php
<?php
$val = "{\"next_offset\":-1,\"records\":[{\"id\":\"e3266222-5389-11ed-ab30-0210c01ad3d2\",\"name\":\"That is a nice name\"}]}";
$val = json_decode($val);

print_r($val->records[0]->id);

?>
```